First Adiabatic Exponent/Index for a degenerate white dwarf
As a short preface, this is not a homework question and is tangentially related to my research.
In Chapter 6 of Shapiro & Teukolsky's Black Holes, White Dawrfs, and Neutron Stars, I came across problem 6.24 and it's made me fall down a rabbit hole I wish to escape from. The first part of the question states:
"Show that for an extremely relativistic, degenerate electron gas,
$$\Gamma_1-\frac{4}{3}\approx\frac{2}{3x^2},"$$
where $\Gamma_1=(\mathrm{d}\log P/ \mathrm{d}\log\rho)_{\mathrm{ad.}}$ is Chandrasekhar's First Adiabatic Exponent/Index, $x=p_\mathrm{F}/m_e$ is the ratio of the Fermi momentum to the electron mass, and $P$ and $\rho$ are the pressure and mass density, respectively. In the extreme relativistic limit, we take $x\gg 1$.
For this limit, the equation of state follows as (in natural units)
$$P(x)\sim \frac{m_e^4}{12\pi^2}x^4 +\mathcal{O}(x^2),$$
$$\varepsilon(x)\sim \frac{m_e^4}{4\pi^2}x^4 +\mathcal{O}(x^2),$$
$$\rho(x)=\frac{\mu m_p m_e^3}{3\pi^2}x^3+\varepsilon(x),$$
where $\varepsilon$ is the energy density, $m_e$ is the electron mass, $m_p$ is the proton mass, and $\mu$ is the mean molecular weight.
Naively, I would think that since this system is at zero temperature and hence zero entropy, $\Gamma_1$ can be calculated simply as
$$\Gamma_1 = \frac{\rho}{P}\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}\rho}=\frac{\rho}{P}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\rho}\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}x},$$
however this evaluates to $\Gamma_1\approx1+\mathcal{O}(x^{-1})$ and not the correct $\Gamma_1\approx \frac{4}{3}+\mathcal{O}(x^{-2})$ as the problem wishes us to show.
Inexplicably, if I instead find the limiting behavior of
$$\Gamma_1\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{\rho+P}{P}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\rho}\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}x},$$
I get the correct form $\Gamma_1\stackrel{?}{\approx}\frac{4}{3} +\frac{2}{3x^2} +\mathcal{O}(x^{-4})$, with the change in the numerator following from a source I can't find again who did not explain it anyway.
It's not remotely obvious to me why $\Gamma_1$ must take this form to get the correct result, especially since the system is degenerate and hence at zero entropy already, so taking the derivative keeping entropy constant should be straightforward, right? Is it the fact we're at zero temperature that complicates things? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Actually, I think I've figured it out, but feel free to read through to check my reasoning.
For any general $x=p_\mathrm{F}/m_e$, the pressure and energy density are calculated as $P(x)=m_e^4\,\phi(x)$ and $\varepsilon(x)=m_e^4\,\chi(x)$, where the functions $\phi$ and $\chi$ are
$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\left[x\sqrt{1+x^2}\left(\frac{2x^2}{3}-1\right)+\sinh^{-1}(x)\right],$$
$$\chi(x)=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\left[x\sqrt{1+x^2}\left(2x^2+1\right)-\sinh^{-1}(x)\right].$$
(I neglected these full forms in the original post since it's cumbersome, but this analysis is simplified a bit by using $\phi$ and $\chi$.)
The internal kinetic energy per unit mass $u$ is the total energy density minus the rest mass energy density of the electron gas, all divided by the density:
$$u = \frac{\varepsilon-m_en_e}{\rho},$$
where $n_e = m_e^3x^3/(3\pi^2)$, which also allows us to parameterize $x$ in terms of the density instead of the Fermi momentum.
From the definition of $\Gamma_1$ in my previous post, we find that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\rho}=\frac{1}{\Gamma_1}\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{P},$$
which we will use later.
From the first law of thermodynamics, an adiabatic (i.e. $\mathrm{d}S=0$) process satisfies
$$\mathrm{d}u=\frac{P}{\rho^2}\mathrm{d}\rho,$$
and upon collecting terms and replacing $\mathrm{d}\rho/\rho$ with the relation found from $\Gamma_1$ above, we get
$$m_e\mathrm{d}n_e-\mathrm{d}\varepsilon=(m_en_e-P-\varepsilon)\frac{1}{\Gamma_1}\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{P}.$$
Using these quantities' definitions based on $x$ and solving for $\Gamma_1$ we find
$$\Gamma_1=\frac{\phi(x)+\chi(x)-x^3/(3\pi^2)}{\chi^\prime(x)-x^2/\pi^2}\frac{\phi^\prime(x)}{\phi(x)},$$
which for $x\gg1$ reduces to (using Mathematica)
$$\Gamma_1=\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2}{3x^2} + \mathcal{O}(x^{-4}),$$
which is the correct limiting behavior, at least to second order in $x$.
